# Как заставить возвращать массив из модуля node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var showTodaySimpleMessages = function () {
    var arrayOfMessages = [];

    var now = new Date();
    var midnight = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()).getTime().toString();

    mongo.connect(config.get('mongodb:uri') + config.get('mongodb:dbName'), function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var col = db.collection(config.get('mongodb:history'));
        var cursor;
        cursor = col.find({_id: {$gt: midnight}});
        cursor.forEach(function (res) {
            if (res.priv.length == 0 && res.confirm.length == 0) {
                mess = res.whoSend + ': ' + res.message;
                arrayOfMessages.push(mess);
            }
        });
    });
    return arrayOfMessages;
};
module.exports = showTodaySimpleMessages;
```

В `forEach` сообщения добавляются, а на выходе - пустота. В чём тут проблема кроется, не подскажете, пожалуйста?

В асинхронности ноды (когда оно в `forEach`, то `return` уже отправился)?

Comment: Да, Вы правы, эта проблема кроется в асинхронности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Колбэк из модуля, ИМХО, плохо используй when или другой deferred/promise:

```
var when = require('when'); // нужно его подключить в dependencies в package.json

function showTodaySimpleMessages () {
    return when.promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var arrayOfMessages = [];

        var now = new Date();
        var midnight = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()).getTime().toString();

        mongo.connect(config.get('mongodb:uri') + config.get('mongodb:dbName'), function (err, db) {
            // Тут по другому
            if (err) { reject(err); return }

            var col = db.collection(config.get('mongodb:history'));
            var cursor;
            cursor = col.find({_id: {$gt: midnight}});
            cursor.forEach(function (res) {
                if (res.priv.length == 0 && res.confirm.length == 0) {
                    arrayOfMessages.push(mess);
                } else {
                    resolve(arrayOfMessages);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

//Вызов
showTodaySimpleMessages().then(
    function(arr){
        // Все хорошо. В arr наш массив
    },
    function(err){
        // Произошла ошибка, в err подробности
    }
);
```

Вобще, код выглядит мягко говоря не рабочим:
- не обрабатывается ошибка на чтение. По опыту, она д.б.
- от куда взялся mess и почему он пушится в массив?

Comment: ,когда убирал все комментарии - по ошибке убрал и эту строку : mess = res.whoSend + ': ' + res.message; ( добавляются все сообщения из базы за сегодня и отсылаются в виде массива , а сервер уже их выводит в окно, чтоб было видно, что за сегодня произошло) . ошибки обрабатывать буду обязательно, но тогда, когда это заработает вроде простое, но которое никак.

Comment: да, отлично, спасибо, всё получилось. правда я сначала ставил резолв снаружи фор_ич, так как вроде как он отправляется один раз и всё на этом. а тут - получается так, как надо.

Comment: Блин, чет я тупанул... каждый раз резолвить - не правильно конечно. Я не знаю точного синтаксиса, но интуитивно, резолв нужно делать в другой ветке IF'а. Поправил код, теперь д.б. норм.

Comment: ненене ) сейчас будет неправильно. оно должно отсекать те сообщения, в которых есть галочка "приватное" или галочка "с подтверждением"(а это и будет else), и показывать только те, которые "для всех". понятно, надо тогда доработать, но всё работает ) спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Навскидку надо сделать так

```
function showTodaySimpleMessages (callback) {
    var arrayOfMessages = [];

    var now = new Date();
    var midnight = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()).getTime().toString();

    mongo.connect(config.get('mongodb:uri') + config.get('mongodb:dbName'), function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var col = db.collection(config.get('mongodb:history'));
        var cursor;
        cursor = col.find({_id: {$gt: midnight}});
        cursor.forEach(function (res) {
            if (res.priv.length == 0 && res.confirm.length == 0) {
                mess = res.whoSend + ': ' + res.message;
                arrayOfMessages.push(mess);
                callback(err, arrayOfMessages);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

а вызывать его надо как-то так

```
showTodaySimpleMessages (function (err , arrayOfMessages) {
    module.exports = arrayOfMessages;
}
```

но тут надо учитывать асинхронность и вызывать module.exports как то иначе

Answer (score 2):

Да, в аснхронности. Сделайте так

```
var getTodaySimpleMessages = function (callback) {
       ...
       callback(resultArray);
```

Или так:

```
var getTodaySimpleMessages = function () {
       return new Promise(function (resolve,reject)
          ...
          resolve(resultArray);
```